# Compiling with objective-c file in Swift project

Tags: swift, compilation

I am working with a framework that is using the Obfuscate. The framework is using a header file to do the obfuscate.
E.g file :

```
#define funcOne            JJmYVBhJqZYKCTJJrEsEr
#define funcTwo            zKqquIfbcRKqMhPXl
#define funcThree          pDeUyAXpAircdITBKBZacBzgCyIL
#define funcFour           SUjJeKmteuaFbcZzg
```

To run this under the "Build Settings" the "Other C Flags" and "Other C++ Flags" added the header file "ExternalObfuscate.h"

By doing this the projects in Objective-c work well.

But the problem is that I am using **project in swift**.

The steps that I did to add the framework to the Swift project was:

I add the "Bridging-Header" and add the header file

```
#import "ExternalObfuscate.h"
```

And also add the location to "Other C Flags" and "Other C++ Flags"

That didn't work, so I decide to copy all the defines to the "Bridging-Header" that didn't work also.

The error that I have all the time is

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_funcOne", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Currently have no ideas of what I can do to resolve this, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Swift handles `#define`s not in usual pre-processor way, so it doesn't replace test in code `as is`. So, probably you will have to do something else.

Comment: Agreed. This entire approach won't work in Swift. You would need to redesign the obfuscator (keeping in mind that ObjC and Swift obfuscators provide very little protection against anything, so I would caution against spending significant time exploring this). Designing a Swift-compatbile obfuscator is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. But I'm sure if you search around GitHub you'll find someone who has built something. Determining whether it has any value is a different issue. (I've found "data hiders" for Swift that are worse than doing nothing at all.)

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, I gonna see what I can do talking with the team that did the framework.